# Getting Error: "Can't bind to 'ngModal' since it isn't a known property of 'input' "

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ngmodel

After Clicking Edit Button, Form should load the Data of the User, by using NgModal. But I am getting an error: "Can't bind to 'ngModal' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"? How to Resolve this error.?

**app.compoment.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div id="registration" class="container col-md-6">

  <form  [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <mat-horizontal-stepper >
      <mat-step  [stepControl]="personal_details">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter Personal Details</ng-template>
        <div class="jumbotron" formGroupName="personal_details">
          <div formGroupName="name">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>First Name : </label>
              <input type="text"  formControlName="first_name" class="form-control"  [(ngModal)]="_trainnerservice.currentTrainner.first_name" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Last Name : </label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" class="form-control" [(ngModal)]="_trainnerservice.currentTrainner.last_name" >
            </div>
          </div>    
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>DOB : </label>
            <input type="date" formControlName="dob" class="form-control" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>About Yourself : </label>
            <textarea formControlName="about_yourself" class="form-control" ></textarea>
          </div>       
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Language(s) : </label>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2" (click)="addLanguage()">Add Language</button>
            <!-- <input type="text" formControlName="lang" class="form-control" [{ngModal}]=""> -->
            <div formArrayName="languages_known" *ngIf="getLangsform()">
              <div *ngFor="let lang of getLangsform().controls; let i =index;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i"><br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Willingly to travel : </label>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="willingly_to_travel" name="willingly_to_travel" value="yes" class="form-control">
            <label>Yes </label>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="willingly_to_travel" name="willingly_to_travel" value="no" class="form-control" >
            <label>No</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container col-md-6">
  <h4 class="display-5 text-center">Trainners Detailed List</h4>
  <table class="table table-hover">
   <tr *ngFor="let trainner of allTrainner">
        <td><a class="btn text-danger" (click)="OnEdit(trainner)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
        <td>{{trainner.personal_details.name.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{trainner.personal_details.name.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{trainner.personal_details.dob}}</td>
        <td>{{trainner.personal_details.about_yourself}}</td>
        <td>{{trainner.personal_details.willingly_to_travel}}</td>

    </tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
OnEdit(trainner) {
   this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner = Object.assign({}, trainner);
  }
```

**trainner.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Trainner } from '../trainner.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


const headerOption = {
  headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TrainnerService {
  _url = 'http://localhost:3000/trainner';

  currentTrainner: Trainner = {
    personal_details: { type: Object,
      name: { type: Object,
          first_name: '',
          last_name: ''
      },
      dob: '',
      about_yourself: '',
      languages_known: [''],
      willingly_to_travel: ''
  },
  technologies: [ Object, {
      type: Object,
          name: '',
          experience: null,
          ratings: null,
          costing: { type: Object,
              freshers: null,
              laterals: null,
              project_specific: null
          },
          work_as_consultant: ''
  }],
  certifications: [Object, {
      title: '',
      Year: null
  }],
};



  constructor( private _http: HttpClient ) { }

  register(registrationFormData) {
    return this._http.post<any>(this._url, registrationFormData);
  }

  getAllTrainner(): Observable<Trainner[]> {
    return this._http.get<Trainner[]>(this._url, headerOption);
  }

  updateUser(trainner: Trainner): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.put(this._url, trainner, headerOption);
  }
}
```

Expect Output: Data should load into the form after the click event occurs

Error: Can't bind to 'ngModal' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Comment: model, not modal (modal is a js/css popover)

Comment: @Sammaye Thanx but em facing one more issue, On clicking the edit button nothing is happening

Comment: why are you using ngModel with reactive forms? Use either ngModel or reactive forms.

Comment: @AJT82 Can Explain me with an example that where m doing wrong?

Comment: If you are asking why you get that error, Sammaye gave you an answer to that :) But yes, as mentioned, you don't need or should use ngModel together with reactive forms, since you have then two separate bindings, which makes no sense. Luckily with newer versions of angular this is deprecated/removed, it's a good thing since this is very misused ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using reactive form, remove [(ngModel)] from first_name and last_name

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>First Name : </label>
   <input type="text"  formControlName="first_name" class="form-control">
</div>
```